# Reading hex data from a file and passing it to a write function which takes data as a string

Tags: python

I would like to pass hex numbers, (example 0xff) into a write function, which takes data in, as a string, example h.write('\xFF') this works.
But when I pass hex numbers from a variable and try to use that data in the write function, I'm unable to do that.Below is the code I've tried.

```
a = 'ff'
h.write('\x%s'%(a))
I also tried
a = 0xff
h.write('\x%x'%(a))
I also tried
a = 0xff
a = str(a)
a = '\\'+'x'+'%s'%(a)
h.write('a')
```

I'm actually using a FTDI ft2232h usb to parallel 8 bit converter.
there are no error messages as such just that I don't see the output on the oscilloscope screen. Only when I hard code it it works, like `h.write('\xFF')`

Python version = 3.6
Os Win7 64bit

Thank you,
Sleeba

Comment: You could use binascii.unhexlify to turn a string like 'ffaa5500' into the byte string equivalent: b'\xff\xaa\x55\x00', but if you're sending data to an oscilloscope surely you'd prefer it if your writing function could accept 8 bit integers instead of hex strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading hex strings from a file and you want to convert them to bytes the simple way is to use [binascii.unhexlify](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify). Here's a short demo.

```
from binascii import unhexlify

src = 'ffaa5500'
out = unhexlify(src)
print(out)
```

**output**

```
b'\xff\xaaU\x00'
```

If you write `out` to a file (or file-like object) opened in binary mode then the file will receive the bytes `\xff`, `\xaa`, `\x55`, `\x00`.

However, if you are generating numerical data that you wish to convert to bytes, the easy way to do that is to use a [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytearray) object. Here's an example that synthesizes a single cycle of a sine wave.

```
from math import radians, sin

# Make a single cycle of a sin wave
data = bytearray()
for i in range(360):
    y = sin(radians(i))
    v = int(0.5 + 127 * (1 + y))
    data.append(v)

with open('scope.bin', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Here's the hexdump of the contents of 'scope.bin':

```
00000000  7f 81 83 86 88 8a 8c 8e  91 93 95 97 99 9c 9e a0  |................|
00000010  a2 a4 a6 a8 aa ad af b1  b3 b5 b7 b9 bb bd bf c0  |................|
00000020  c2 c4 c6 c8 ca cb cd cf  d1 d2 d4 d6 d7 d9 da dc  |................|
00000030  dd df e0 e2 e3 e4 e6 e7  e8 ea eb ec ed ee ef f0  |................|
00000040  f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f6 f7  f8 f8 f9 fa fa fb fb fc  |................|
00000050  fc fc fd fd fd fe fe fe  fe fe fe fe fe fe fe fe  |................|
00000060  fd fd fd fc fc fc fb fb  fa fa f9 f8 f8 f7 f6 f6  |................|
00000070  f5 f4 f3 f2 f1 f0 ef ee  ed ec eb ea e8 e7 e6 e4  |................|
00000080  e3 e2 e0 df dd dc da d9  d7 d6 d4 d2 d1 cf cd cb  |................|
00000090  ca c8 c6 c4 c2 c0 bf bd  bb b9 b7 b5 b3 b1 af ad  |................|
000000a0  aa a8 a6 a4 a2 a0 9e 9c  99 97 95 93 91 8e 8c 8a  |................|
000000b0  88 86 83 81 7f 7d 7b 78  76 74 72 70 6d 6b 69 67  |.....}{xvtrpmkig|
000000c0  65 62 60 5e 5c 5a 58 56  54 51 4f 4d 4b 49 47 45  |eb`^\ZXVTQOMKIGE|
000000d0  43 41 3f 3e 3c 3a 38 36  34 33 31 2f 2d 2c 2a 28  |CA?><:86431/-,*(|
000000e0  27 25 24 22 21 1f 1e 1c  1b 1a 18 17 16 14 13 12  |'%$"!...........|
000000f0  11 10 0f 0e 0d 0c 0b 0a  09 08 08 07 06 06 05 04  |................|
00000100  04 03 03 02 02 02 01 01  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000110  00 00 00 00 01 01 01 02  02 02 03 03 04 04 05 06  |................|
00000120  06 07 08 08 09 0a 0b 0c  0d 0e 0f 10 11 12 13 14  |................|
00000130  16 17 18 1a 1b 1c 1e 1f  21 22 24 25 27 28 2a 2c  |........!"$%'(*,|
00000140  2d 2f 31 33 34 36 38 3a  3c 3e 3f 41 43 45 47 49  |-/13468:<>?ACEGI|
00000150  4b 4d 4f 51 54 56 58 5a  5c 5e 60 62 65 67 69 6b  |KMOQTVXZ\^`begik|
00000160  6d 70 72 74 76 78 7b 7d                           |mprtvx{}|
00000168
```